# Automatically opening multiple Apps / TABs for certain projects

Tags: macos, productivity

I'm trying to improve my workflow when working on certain projects. Depending on what kind of work I'm doing, I'll want certain apps open with certain configurations.

**Example:**

For a web development project, I'll want to open iTerm 2, have 2 horizontal panes. The upper pane will go into the frontend folder, the other one will go into the backend folder. Then, I want to have both folders also open up in Sublime Text.

Ideally, I'd like to have an app or a file or a script or something, that does this for me so that I don't have to do this every time I want to work on whatever project:

```
- Launch iTerm
- Hit CMD-ENTER for fullscreen
- Hit CMD-SHIFT-D for two horizontal panes
- Run "cd to/project/backend"
- Run "subl src" to open "src" folder in Sublime Text
- Run "vagrant up"
- Close Sublime windows I had open last time I quit it
- Hit CMD-ALT-UP to go to upper pane
- Run "cd to/project/frontend"
- Run "subl ." to open new Sublime window here
- Launch Chrome and open up my frontend in a new tab
```

That's just one example. When I'm working on something else, I might want Sketch and Keynote open with certain files (no terminal at all).

**I'm looking for a way to automate these processes. Grateful for any suggestions. Thank you! :)**

Comment: See what you can do with [Automator](http://sc5.io/blog/2014/01/use-os-x-automator-to-open-workspaces/)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a 'boot' shell script to do most of what you're describing and bind it to an **iTerm2** profile. You can configure a profile to have a specific window arrangement (it is a feature of **iTerm2**), see ***iTerm2*** > Preferences > Arrangements to save your current arrangement as a **preset**.

Then, make a new profile that executes a startup script and applies the aforementioned window arrangement as its default arrangement (***iTerm2*** > Profiles > Open Profiles > Edit Profiles). Ideally, you would bind launching this profile to a shortcut, like `Command + Control + D` for one-keystroke access.

In said profile, under the *General Tab > Command* section, the startup command should be a shell script akin to below:

I don't know why it's necessary for you to open up the sublimetext frontend and backend in different terminal windows. Whenever you run `subl`, it opens the app as a daemon, as `subl` is just a python wrapper that launches the OS X app.

Sample rough `startup.sh` script I scaffolded up for ya:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/to/project/backend
open . # open Finder window of backend folder
subl . # open SublimeText instance of backend folder

cd ~/to/project/frontend
open . # open Finder window of frontend folder
subl . # open SublimeText instance of frontend folder

# Launch chrome and navigate to http://localhost:8000/ or wherever your dev location is
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://localhost:8000/' 

echo 'COME AT ME BRO'
```

You should change the settings on SublimeText to not remember your window/tab arrangements from previous launch instead of attempting to script it to close all of your windows from before.

Alternatively, you could have `subl` open a native, `.sublimetext-workspace` or `.sublimetext-project` file and achieve more precise results than with `subl .`